# Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation

Tags: ignite

How can I solve this problem when using ignite ?

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Grid is in invalid state to perform this operation. It either not started yet or has already being or have stopped [gridName=grid.cfg, state=STOPPED]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.illegalState(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:190)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.GridKernalGatewayImpl.readLock(GridKernalGatewayImpl.java:90)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterGroupAdapter.guard(ClusterGroupAdapter.java:170)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterGroupAdapter.forPredicate(ClusterGroupAdapter.java:367)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.cluster.ClusterGroupAdapter.forServers(ClusterGroupAdapter.java:392)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.services(IgniteKernal.java:363)
        at org.apache.ignite.IgniteSpringBean.services(IgniteSpringBean.java:156)

Comment: Can you post the code that generates this?  It looks like you're trying to use ignite before you do `Ignition.start()` or after after you already called `Ignition.stop()`

Answer (score 1):

This exception means that you're trying to use Ignite after it was already stopped. You should check the logs for any exceptions and also your code - there can be a mistake or some race condition.